Create a Histogram based on the date range
I am new to Data Science and Python.
I have a Data Set with date range Starting: "2020-03-15" and Ending: "2022-02-23". On each date there are multiple activities.
I am looking forward to create a Histogram to display the number of activities in the y-axis. On the x-axis I want to distribute the date range in quarterly bin (buckets).
e.g
y-axis = Number of counter
x-axis = Q1-2020 (2020-03-15 to 2020-03-31), Q2-2020 (2020-04-01 to 2020-06-30), ... END

If there is a better solution then please direct or guide. Can any body please help or guide me here.

Hi there. Self-answered Q&A is perfectly fine, but the question needs to live up to the same standards as a regular question. As in, there needs to be a specific problem and some manner of attempt to solve it. You could fix this by for example editing in the problematic code which didn't get the desired results and then in the answer explain how the changes solved the problem.

@Lundin, thanks for responding. I was actually looking for a help and I was not able to receive any help from Stack Overflow community. In the mean time I was also doing research on my own and that's how I landed in a solution that answered my own question. But thanks for reaching out and for next time I will add an explanation to the answer.

I was able to create a solution as below:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter

ax = df.hist(column='COLUMN_NAME', bins=25, grid=False, figsize=(12,8), color='#274490', zorder=2, rwidth=0.9)

ax = ax[0]
for x in ax:

    # Despine
    x.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    x.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    x.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

    # Switch off ticks
    x.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off", labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")

    # Draw horizontal axis lines
    vals = x.get_yticks()
    for tick in vals:
        x.axhline(y=tick, linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.4, color='#eeeeee', zorder=1)

    # Remove title
    x.set_title("")

    # Set x-axis label
    x.set_xlabel("Distribution", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)

    # Set y-axis label
    x.set_ylabel("Observations", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)

    # Format y-axis label
    x.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,g}'))

